# How to join the subquery result(having nested joins ) with another table?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am implementing nested join statement using sub-queries. I am able to get the result for 3 tables but unable to join it further for four or n tables .

```
SELECT X.personCityId
     , X.name
     , X.age
     , X.cityId
     , X.state
     , Y.age 
     , Y.name 
  FROM (SELECT Person.cityId AS personCityId
             , Person.name
             , Person.age
             , CityDetails.cityId AS cityId
             , CityDetails.state 
          FROM Person 
               LEFT JOIN CityDetails 
                      ON Person.cityid = CityDetails.cityid ) AS X 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT name , age, lastname FROM PersonalDetails) AS Y 
               ON X.age=Y.age
```

Let say if i have to join result of above query with  4th table by left join on `age` column

`LEFT JOIN (SELECT age,height, weight from PersonMedicalRecords ) as D ON Z.age = a.age`

I want to know how this can be done through sub-queries only.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT age,height, weight from PersonMedicalRecords ) as D ON Z.age = a.age` is exactly the same as `LEFT JOIN PersonMedicalRecords  as D ON Z.age = a.age` the sub-query is useless. Neither of your sub-queries are needed. Why don't you join directly to the tables? That makes the query way easier to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use "common table expression" to achieve this and maintain level wise hierarchy
Like this

```
; 
WITH cte AS (
         SELECT Person.cityId AS personCityId
              , Person.name
              , Person.age
              , CityDetails.cityId AS cityId
              , CityDetails.state 
           FROM Person 
                LEFT JOIN CityDetails 
                       ON Person.cityid = CityDetails.cityid )
   , ct AS ( 
        SELECT *                    ----- here on * use your required column
          FROM (SELECT *            ----- here on * use your required column
                  FROM cte) AS x 
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT name 
                               , age
                               , lastname 
                           FROM PersonalDetails) as y 
                      ON X.age=y.age )  
   , ct2 AS ( 
         SELECT *                  ----- here on * use your required column
           FROM (SELECT *          ----- here on * use your required column
                   FROM ct) as y 
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT height 
                                , weight 
                                , age    ---- added from our side considering it is available for implementing join on age
                             FROM PersonMedicalRecords) as z 
                       ON y.age=z.age )   
SELECT * FROM ct2   ----- here on * use your required column
```

Here output of one `left join` will take as input table with next `join` and similarly you can maintain your hierarchy of `join`.

Comment: The extra selects from the `cte` table (as `x` and `y`) are unnecessary - just put the cte table directly in the from clause. Also, you could simplify the query further by moving the innermost selects further out. This would also solve the problem that, in your query as written, there is no `age` column selected in `z` to join on, because it has been filtered out too soon.

Comment: op is willing to do n number of joins in our question and maintaining subquery in that way is difficult to maintain, this will create each join individually. moreover this is just another option to do this task, for the case of age column not in z, it is in his query on input...let me update by considering that age is available in PersonMedicalRecords table

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily nesting your queries.  You should write your query as:

```
SELECT p.cityId as personCityId, p.name, p.age, 
       cd.cityId, cd.state,
       pd.age, pd.name 
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
     CityDetails cd
     ON p.cityid = cd.cityid LEFT JOIN
     PersonalDetails pd
     ON pd.age = p.age;
```

Note the use of meaningful table aliases (abbreviations for the table names) rather than arbitrary letters.  Also, no subqueries.

If you want to add another `JOIN`, just add another `JOIN`, following the pattern of the other joins.

Comment: I have reasons to writing it in sub-query format. My caches are distributres .and we are using Ignite platform which do not support non-collocated nested joins.so have to come up with sub-queries ,where one join function works at a time.

Comment: To implement distributed joins either we must have an affinity key with nested joins or we choose this way of implementation.

Answer (score -2):

**I tried this and it works

SELECT X.personCityId, X.name, X.age, X.cityId, X.state, Y.age FROM (SELECT Person.cityId AS personCityId, Person.name, Person.age, CityDetails.cityId AS cityId, CityDetails.state FROM Person LEFT JOIN CityDetails ON Person.cityid = CityDetails.cityid) AS X LEFT JOIN (SELECT age, lastname FROM PersonalDetails) AS Y ON X.age=Y.age LEFT JOIN (SELECT age, height, weight FROM PersonMedicalRecords)AS Z ON Y.age = Z.age

---